# get Length of Jagged Array in C

Tags: c, pointers

CODE :

```
int *Array[8];

  Array[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

  printf("%d" , sizeof(Array)/sizeof(int));  // Result = 8 : True
  printf("%d" , sizeof(Array[0])/sizeof(int)); // Result = 1 : False
```

How do I get length of Array[0] that is 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

Dynamic arrays in C don't carry around their length information with them.  So you'll need to write your code to remember that it allocated something of length 5.

Comment: This is only partly true. You can check the size of arrays when it can be computed at compile time, e.g. ``int myary[8]; sizeof(myary) / sizeof(int)``

Comment: @ckruse: That's why I said "dynamic arrays".

Comment: Hm, I am blind or dumb. I didn't see the "dynamic", sorry.